# Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'DocMapUpdatePanelId' is not a property or an existing field when trying to run report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I am having an issue with my Report Viewer. I have installed Reports Viewer 2015 Runtime on my machine but whenever I try to run the report, I get the following:

Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: 'DocMapUpdatePanelId' is not a property or an existing field.

This what calls the Report Viewer:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="true" SizeToReportContent="True" Width="100%" Height="500px"> </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

At the top of the aspx page, I have:

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

and my web.config is as such:

```
 <system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design  , Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

also under system.webServer I have the following:

```
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

at this point, I am unsure how to get this resolved.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid fix but I removed Report Viewer Runtime 2015 from Nuget and added Report Viewer Runtime 2012. Changed all my references to version 11 and the reports started working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this `ReportViewer` HTTP handler named `ReportViewerWebControlHandler` in web.config inside `system.webserver` section (note that `resourceType` set to `Unspecified`):

```
<system.webserver>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" 
         preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
         path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler"
         resourceType="Unspecified" />
</system.webserver>
```

If you have multiple references of `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` assembly, stick to the latest or available assembly reference (i.e. 12.0) and remove duplicate reference(s).

Reference:

[ReportViewer gives JS error: 0x800a139e 'DocMapUpdatePanelId' is not a property or an existing field](https://forums.asp.net/t/2109211.aspx?ReportViewer%20gives%20JS%20error%200x800a139e%20DocMapUpdatePanelId%20is%20not%20a%20property%20or%20an%20existing%20field%20)

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to mention that I have already put that in there: <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />